# Unity オブジェクトを引っ張って飛ばす

Tags: unity3d

Unity２Dで画面上の任意のゲームオブジェクトを引っ張ると引っ張った方向と逆に飛ぶという処理を書きたいのですが、今のところ皆目見当がつかず困っております。
参考になるチュートリアルやリファレンス等ご存知でしたら、教えていただけると幸いです
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

Angry Birdsの公式チュートリアルがありますが、いかがでしょうか。

https://unity3d.com/jp/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/making-angry-birds-style-game

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます